# Atomic integer parts

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ordered-fields

Let $R$ be an ordered ring (in particular, the order is linear and $R$ is a domain). Let $| \ \  |: x \mapsto \max(x,-x)$ denote its absolute value.

For $(x,y) \in R \times R^{\neq 0}$ say that an **euclidean division** of $(x,y)$ is an ordered pair $(q,r) \in R^2$ with $x = yq +r$ and $0 \leq r < |y|$.

Say that $R$ is an ordered ring with euclidean divisions if any $(a,b) \in R \times R^{\neq 0}$ has an euclidean division in $R$.

If $R$ is discrete (that is $1 = \min(R^{>0})$), this is equivalent to saying that $R$ is an integer part of some ordered field (namely, any dense extension of its fraction field).

The classical example of such rings is $\mathbb{Z}$, but one can also mention the ring $\mathbb{Z} + X\mathbb{Q}[X]$ ordered so that $X> \mathbb{Q}$, and more generally the ring of elements in the Hahn series field $F((x^{\Gamma}))$ whose support is in $\Gamma^{\leq 0}$ and which take values in an integer part $Z$ of $F$ at $0_{\Gamma}$.

Most of the constructions I know of those types of rings (integer parts of ordered fields) are similar to the previous ones and fail to be factorial or even atomic (=every non-unit non-zero element is a product of irreducibles). In fact most of them have non zero elements with infinite $2$-adic valuation. I don't suspect the latter fact is general but I wonder if atomicity in this context is reserved for the archimedean case:

> **Question**: Are there *atomic* discrete ordered ring with euclidean divisions besides $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Some definitions appear to be missing a reference.

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais Could you tell me which ones so that I can amend my post accordingly?

Comment: The definition of atomic might be useful .